# How to determine the columns generated when uploading a KML into a Google Fusion table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, kml, google-fusion-tables

I created a Road Segment shapefile with ArcGIS desktop, the shapefile has the following columns:'CellID' 'RoadName' 'Description' Like so:

[image]

I converted into a KMZ file which I then converted into a KML. My goal is to upload that kml to a google fusion table and display it on a google map and merge it with the rest of its data based on the CellID column, when I upload the file to a Fusion Table there are only 3 Columns present Like so:

[image]

How can I get the 'CellID' column to generate in the Fusion Table? my real data has more columns however If I cannot figure out how to do it with basic data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KML did not want to have the 'CellID' as a naming convention, a simple change to 'Name' worked just fine.

Comment: @Mapperz I have to wait 23 hours